# Awesome WM can't find xcb-cursor 12.04

Tags: 12.04, awesome

I'm trying to install awesome wm following: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Awesome-3.4.11/git-Ubuntu-Lucid

but instead of installing

> libxcb-1.8, xcb-proto-1.7, xcb-util-0.3.8 and xcb-util-wm-0.3.8

I installed

> libxcb-1.9.1   xcb-util-0.3.9             xcb-util-wm-0.3.9
>   xcb-proto-1.8  xcb-util-renderutil-0.3.8

When I try to compile awesome I get the following error:

> package 'xcb-cursor' not found
>   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
>    A required package was not found

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 2):

You need `xcb-util-cursor`. It's probably not in any Ubuntu repository yet, so you'd need to get and compile it yourself.

Homepage: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/util-cursor